# Should we merge [4G] and [LTE] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should the [4g](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4g) and [lte](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lte) be merged? Whilst there might technically be a difference between them I don't think most users realise (or care) and both terms are used interchangeably.

> **What is LTE?**
>
> Though originally marketed as 4G technology, LTE (Long Term Evolution) didn't satisfy the technical requirements that the ITU-R outlined, meaning that many early tariffs sold as 4G weren't actually 4G.
>
> However, due to marketing pressures and the significant advancements that LTE brings to original 3G technologies, the ITU later decided that LTE could be called 4G technology.

[Source](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/feature/mobile-phone/whats-difference-between-4g-lte-3605656/)

Comment: Good question, I can't think of a real case where it's necessary to distinguish from the PoV of Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have merged them, with [4g](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4g) as the master and [lte](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lte) as a synonym.  There was significant overlap anyways so I agree that we have mostly been using them interchangeably; someone can always specify in the question if the case comes up where it's important.

Comment: I think that this is a good decision